# Can't get rotating skybox to work in v2019.3.15f1

Tags: unity-game-engine

So most google hits for rotating skybox suggest putting something this in an Update:

```
RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Rotation", Time.time * 1.23f);
```

Or something like this if you have a skybox component on your camera:

```
GetComponent<Skybox>().material.SetFloat("_Rotation", Time.time * 1.23f);
```

I've tried both with the first method (without a skybox component on the camera) and the second method (with a skybox component on the camera) and neither work. There is no error thrown fwiw. Also I am able to change the skybox material at runtime no problem, so it's not that I'm unable to access the material, it seems more that setting the _Rotation is having no effect.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tested

```
void Update()
{
    RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Rotation", Time.time * 1.23f);
}
```

and it seems to work fine for me.

What type of shader are you using in your skybox material?
I just tested it with the `Skybox/6 Sided` shader.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the crux of it. I'm using a custom skybox material from a unity asset I bought and it does not use the Skybox/6 sided, but a custom skybox shader and hence doesn't appear to use the _Rotation, or at least not in the same way. I'm going to email the asset maker and ask what I need to do to rotate it. I tested with a Skybox/6sided shader and it worked fine now fwiw.